# Angular.js memory issue with add & removing nodes, graph attached, ng-repeat

Tags: memory, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm adding and removing html elements to make and infinity scroll.. But angular doesnt seem to be garbage collecting straight away.. Please have a look at the graph.

It climbs and climbs and then drops while scrolling..

[image]

and here is a sample of my code:

```
$scope.items = and array of lots of items.
$scope.itemsView.push($scope.item[i]);
$scope.itemsView.splice(theIndex,1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not up to Angular to do the garbage collecting, it's only responsible for removing the HTML elements from the DOM. I can't see from your graph whether Angular is doing its job or not.

Did you try forcing a GC by pressing the garbage bin icon at the bottom of Chrome Dev Tools? Chrome will do a GC when it deems it necessary and not instantly since it's a costly operation.